# Globular 3-cells and higher diagrams in xy-pic

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

Is there a nice/standardized way to format globular 3-cells in `xy-pic` the same way we can with 2-cells?

[image]

For 2-cells the command `\rtwocell`  generates the required arrows, and a modification that allows one to type `\rncell` for natural numbers n would be incredible for writing category theory papers and [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) pages.

I found a [page](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lauda/xy/Globular/glob3cell.html) describing how to define globular 3-cells back in 2004, but `xy-pic` appears to have changed syntax significantly since then (or at least I am too green behind the ears to read the code there and translate it to something that works in my version of `xy-pic`). Can someone more knowledgable in LaTeX renovate these codes to work with modern `xy-pic` syntax?

Any strategy that generalizes to higher cells with arrows between arrows between arrows between... would be beautiful, but a solution for 3-cells is still greatly appreciated. Also please note that `tikz` solutions will be somewhat incomprehensible to me due to a lack of familiarity with the syntax, however, if there is no `xy-pic` solution (and no kind samaritan willing to create one) and `tikz` has an elegant solution on hand I can learn some new syntax and use a `tikz` diagram.

---

The following code

```
\xymatrix@R5mm@C10mm{ & \ar@{=>}@/^.7pc/[dd]^\Theta \ar@{=>}@/_.7pc/[dd]_{\;\;\;\Theta'} \\ A \ar@/^2.0pc/[rr]^F \ar@/_2.1pc/[rr]_G & {\substack{\mathscr{M} \\ \rightsquigarrow}} & B \\ & }
```

generates the diagram below

[image]

and it's relatively straightforward (but time-consuming) to generalize further, but this is pretty hacked together and very time consuming for larger diagrams so a more elegant solution would still be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) it is not difficult.

The `&` are used to separate the cells (and `\\` to separate the rows, if you have more rows).

`\arrow[rr, bend left=40, "F", ""{name=U}]` means "draw an arrow, bent to the left of 40 degrees, with the label "F" and call the middle point "U"."

`\arrow[Rightarrow, "\Theta", shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend left=40, from=U, to=D]` means "draw a Rightarrow, labelling it with `\Theta`, shortening a bit (2pt) the tip and the tail of the arrow, bending to the left from the point called "U" to the point called "D"."

I don't know anything about Globular diagrams, I've just written an example of how to use `tikz-cd`.

*Edit:* for peculiar cases, a pure TikZ solution may be convenient.

I've added one with a TikZ `matrix`. If you use it without loading `tikz-cd`, you have to load `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`.

You can refer to the matrix cells with `matrixname-rownumber-columnnumber`.

`\node[above=16pt of mymatr, inner sep=12pt] (UP) {};` means "position the node `UP` 16pt above of `mymatr`, since the node has an empty text, I've given it an height with `inner sep=12pt`."

`\draw[double distance=2pt, -{Implies}] (UP.south) -- (DOWN.north);` means "draw an arrow, with `Implies` arrow tip, and with 2pt distance between the two rows of the arrows, between the south point of node `UP` and the north point of point `DOWN`."

`\draw ([xshift=-10pt]UP.south) edge[bend right=60, double distance=2pt, -{Implies}] ([xshift=-10pt]DOWN.north);` means "draw an `Implies` arrow, bent right of 60 degrees, from a point shifted horizontally -10pt from `UP.south` to a point shifted horizontally -10pt from `DOWN.north`."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            A
            \arrow[rr, bend left=40, "F", ""{name=U}]
            \arrow[rr, bend right=40, "G", swap, ""{name=D}] 
            & 
            M 
            & 
            B 
            \arrow[rr, bend left=40, "A", ""{name=A}]
            \arrow[rr, bend right=40, "B", swap, ""{name=B}]
            & 
            \Rrightarrow
            & 
            \bullet
            \arrow[Rightarrow, "\Theta", shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend left=40, from=U, to=D]
            \arrow[Rightarrow, "\Theta'", shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend right=40, swap, from=U, to=D]
            \arrow[Rightarrow, "\Phi", shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend left=40, from=A, to=B]
            \arrow[Rightarrow, "\Phi'", shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend right=40, swap, from=A, to=B]
        \end{tikzcd}    
    \]
    \[
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[matrix of math nodes,
                nodes in empty cells]
                (mymatr) {
                \bullet &[20pt] \Rrightarrow &[10pt] \Rrightarrow &[20pt] \bullet\\
                };
            \node[above=16pt of mymatr, inner sep=12pt] (UP) {};
            \node[below=16pt of mymatr, inner sep=12pt] (DOWN) {};
            \draw[->, rounded corners=40pt] (mymatr-1-1) -- (UP.north) -- (mymatr-1-4);
            \draw[->, rounded corners=40pt] (mymatr-1-1) -- (DOWN.south) -- (mymatr-1-4);
            \draw[double distance=2pt, -{Implies}] (UP.south) -- (DOWN.north);
            \draw ([xshift=10pt]UP.south) edge[bend left=60, double distance=2pt, -{Implies}] ([xshift=10pt]DOWN.north);
            \draw ([xshift=-10pt]UP.south) edge[bend right=60, double distance=2pt, -{Implies}] ([xshift=-10pt]DOWN.north);
        \end{tikzpicture}    
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I adding my upvote because this nice answer not can be = 0.

Comment: Upvoted as well and much appreciated, the explanation of syntax is particularly nice — if no xypic solutions come by in the near future I’ll accept and adapt.

Comment: @AlecRhea Thank you, I answered because nobody else did. I added a pure TikZ solution, I think it could be convenient for peculiar cases.

Comment: Accepted and thank you for the additional solution, for more complicated diagrams it will likely come in handy.

Comment: @AlecRhea You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer.